# How to return value in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Composable` with a `Box`and some text and it also returns a value
How to use that value

```
@Composable
fun dummyAndUselessUI(String:String) : String{
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)){ Text(String) }
    return text.value
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a function that return a value, in Compose you handle [State](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun dummyScreen() {
    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    dummyAndUselessUI(text = text, onNameChange = { text = it })
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun dummyAndUselessUI(text: String, onTextChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)){ 
       OutlinedTextField(
          value = text,
          onValueChange = onTextChange,
          label = { Text("Name") }
       )
    }
}
```